# Parse XML inputstream in Blackberry Java application

Tags: java, xml, blackberry

I am getting an XML in inputstream on calling a dotnet web service from my Blackberry native Java application. This XML contains tags with some attribute-value pairs.

How to parse this XML (I think with SAX parser) to get each and everything (i.e. tag name, their attribute-value pairs and all)?

My XML inputstream response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SeatLayout>
  <objArea colRows="Bigtree.colRows" intSeatsOrdered="0" strAreaCode="0000000003">
    <colRows colSeats="Bigtree.colSeats" intGridRowID="1">
      <colSeats Key="S1" strGridSeatNum="1" />
      <colSeats Key="S2" strGridSeatNum="2" />
   </colRows>
  </objArea>
  <objArea colRows="Bigtree.colRows" intSeatsOrdered="0" strAreaCode="0000000002">
    <colRows colSeats="Bigtree.colSeats" intGridRowID="1">
      <colSeats Key="S1" strGridSeatNum="1" />
      <colSeats Key="S2" strGridSeatNum="2" />
    </colRows>
    <colRows colSeats="Bigtree.colSeats" intGridRowID="4">
      <colSeats Key="S1" strGridSeatNum="1" />
    </colRows>
    <colRows colSeats="Bigtree.colSeats" intGridRowID="5">
      <colSeats Key="" strGridSeatNum="0" />
      <colSeats Key="S6" strGridSeatNum="6" />
    </colRows>
  </objArea>
</SeatLayout>
```

Comment: You can get started by looking at the example [here on blackberry.com](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Use-the-XML-Parser/ta-p/445210).

Comment: refer http://rincethomas.blogspot.in/2012/04/xml-parsing-in-bb.html

Comment: Quite a number of samples on the BB forum too, including: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/XML-parsing-using-SAX-Parser/m-p/1940857#M209570, and http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Xml-parsing-using-sax-parser/m-p/1651051#M195583

Answer (score 0):

for this you need a xml parser.and i recommended to work with SAX parser.below is the working example.
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/